# Changing body background colour using array?

Tags: php

I'm trying to change the body background colour using php, with the colours in the array.

Here is the code:

```
 <?php 
   $days = array("blue", "green", "red", "Yellow", "Black", "aqua", "white"); 
   //$today = date('w'); 
   echo "<body style="background-color:' + $days[1] + "\"/>";
   ?>
```

It looks like it should work to me but it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Try it like

```
   echo '<body style="background-color:' . $days[1] . ';">';
```

In `PHP` concatination will be done by `.` operator where as in `javascript` it will be taken by `+` operator

Comment: Gautam, you were wrong initially. You changed the answer later.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran but I have changed it before you have answered ;-).I forgot to change them first in hurry

Answer (score 1):

You are using a wrong concatenation operator. Make **`+`** to **`.`**

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<body style="background-color:', $days[1], ';">';
// Don't concat on echo! Use "," instead of ".".
```